# How To Change The Title Color of an MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have in-app email using the MessageUI Framework. Everything works fine with the MFMailComposeViewController, but I want to change the title color from black to white. As of now, it looks like this: [image]

I also want to change the bar button items to white. I was able to achieve all of this with all of my other views, but I simply don't know how to do this with an MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set Title Text Attributes Of Navigation Bar in `MFMailComposeViewController`

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailVc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailVc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[[mailVc navigationBar] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName]];
```

Comment: @RehaanAdvani Welcome anytime :)